# (Swift) Moving views out of the way for keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, keyboard

I am having a weird problem with moving my views to make room for an incoming keyboard. Basically, in my app, there is a button that performs a segue which pushes a new instance of a view controller that is embedded inside of a navigation controller modally. Within this first instance, my keyboard code works perfectly. The code is as follows:

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    if !keyBoard {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= 200
    }
    keyBoard = true
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    if keyBoard {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += 200
    }
    keyBoard = false
}
```

with the following in viewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

I also added a tapGestureRecognizer so that when the keyboard is showing and the user taps anywhere on the screen, the keyboard closes:

```
let tapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "closeKeyboard")
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
```

and

```
func closeKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

So in the first instance, this code works perfectly. However, after I go back, calling self.dismissViewControllerAnimated, and, once I am on the original screen, click the button that calls performSegue again and push a new instance of this same view controller, the code breaks and the view no longer moves out of the way of the keyboard but just sort of stutters and bounces a little. I have no idea why this is happening and any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a breakpoint on `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide`, and tell me if both the methods are called when you go back to the second ViewController.

Comment: yes the methods are called. they just seem to stop working in the same way